# Is there any Inheritance problem with <table> and it's elements, like <form> elements?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

Is there any Inheritance problem with `<table>`, `tr` `th` `td` `tbody` `thead` `tfoot` also like form elements?

In IE 6+ and FF 3+ with Strict doctype.

> Tables also have inheritance turned off in some browsers. You may
>   notice that in some browsers, your
>   tables’ text will be larger, clunkier
>   and not so pretty. This is also due to
>   inheritance. Many browsers give tables
>   their own style.

It's mentioned here http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2006/10/css-trickery-part-5-inheritance/

For which browsers author is talking about, it's not mentioned

[I tested on FF 3.6 and IE7 but unable to find is there any issue.](http://jsbin.com/ucano4/8)

I just wanted to be sure before adding this in my CSS reset. Do i really need this?

```
table  {
       font-family:inherit;
       font-size:inherit;
       font-weight:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Is this a real question? What is an "inheritance problem"? And couldn't you figure the answer out yourself anyway with 5 minutes and a copy of IE6/FF?

Comment: @codeka, this seems a reasonable question, and it links to a page explaining the possible inheritance problem. I agree that if he is writing his own CSS reset then he also needs to find the answer by testing rather than asking.

Comment: @Sean Hogan - I tested on FF 3.6 and IE7 but unable to find is there any issue. I don't have IE6 and other browsers. I can't downgrade my IE and FF. Could you please test on other browsers? I made an example http://jsbin.com/ucano4/8

Comment: Use [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) (don't see any difference btw).  The real issue might only be the `th` since its boldness indeed *may* differ among browsers.

Comment: @ BalusC - Thanks for testing. but `th` boldness  is not a inheritance problem even if it is.

Comment: @Sean Hogan: The question's been updated to add more details since I commented, so my comment isn't *quite* as appropriate any more :)

Comment: @codeka - You are right It's my mistake . my question had not much details at start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason here http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/199903.html

And it's problem only in

> Internet Explorer 4.x for Windows, or
>   Navigator 4.x on any platform.

here also http://archive.webstandards.org/css/winie/#Inheritance_breakdown_within_tables